# How to get the counts of Student for each Teachers in a single collection by Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, subquery

A Teacher has many Students. When I am showing the Teachers list I also want to show the counts of Student for each Teachers. How can I do this by using Eloquent?

I can find the Teachers from this,
`$teacher= Teacher::where('teacher_status','active')->get();`

I can find the Student count from this
`$student_count = Student::where('teacher_id','teachers.id')->count();`

How can I conbine this two query and return the response in a single array/collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your teacher model, create the relationship students:**

```
class Teacher extends Model
{
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class, 'teacher_id');
    }
}
```

**In your controller you can do the following:**

```
public function example(){
    $teachers = Teacher::where('teacher_status','active')->withCount('students')->get();
    
    return view('teacherViewExample', compact('teachers'));
}
```

**In your view** (teacherViewExample):

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Teacher Name</th>
      <th>Students Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($teachers as $teacher)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $teacher->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $teacher->students_count }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Full documentation on how to use `withCount()` here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

> Sometimes you may want to count the number of related models for a
> given relationship without actually loading the models. To accomplish
> this, you may use the withCount method. The withCount method will
> place a {relation}_count attribute on the resulting models:

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the number of students related to teacher without actually loading them you may use the withCount method and this add new propery named by  a {relation}_count column on your resulting models. For example:

```
Teacher::where('teacher_status','active')->withCount('students')->get();
```

**Also you need and to your Teacher model hasMany relation method to Students**

Answer (score 0):

In case frontend and backend are separated, i.e Laravel for backend, Angular for frontend, below are examples for Laravel:

In api.php,

```
Route::get('teacher-with-students-count', 'TeacherController@getTeacherWithStudentsCount');
```

In Teacher.php (model)

```
class Teacher extends Model
{
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class, 'teacher_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

In TeacherController.php

```
public function getTeacherWithStudentsCount()
    {
        $teachers = Teacher::where('teacher_status','active')->withCount('students')->get();

        return $this->giveSuccessResponse($teachers);
    }
```